# tfs/tf.exe: print currently checked out version

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I used tf.exe to get a particular version of a source tree like:

```
$ tf get $/[PATH]/[SUBPATH] /r /version:C1234
```

Now I want to check the last checkin, but only up to the version as checked out. I tried:

```
$ tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:1~W
```

However, this prints the tip of the source tree as in source control.

```
Changeset User
--------- ----------------
1555      domain\[USER]
```

Is there a command option to only show the history of the tree as it is checked out (excluding any changes that may exist on the server, but are not checked out locally), i.e. for the example above, the output should be

```
Changeset User
--------- ----------------
1234      domain\[USER]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the command above works after I re-get the workspace but also undid all local changes. In my previous attempt I had kept two local edits (answered "Keep Local Version" to the conflict resolution prompt). Looks like this caused the history command to return the latest server version.